# Visual Studio 2022 Debug Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, remote-debugging, visual-studio-2022

I was following multiple articles to how to debug an azure app service on vs 2022. I learned that cloud explorer is deprecated in 2022 so I ran into this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69549657/visual-studio-2022-debug-on-remote-azure-server) and after I attach the debugger on the hosting section, I keep stumbling across one main issue.

> The Visual Studio 2022 Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) does not
> appear to be running on the remote computer. This may be because a firewall is preventing communication to the remote
> computer. Please see Help for assistance on configuring remote debugging

I went to Windows Defender Firewall -> Allow an app or feature through Windows Defender Firewall and made sure that Visual Studio 2022 Remote Debugger was checked. I even went to the directory where my VS is installed and went to Common7/IDE/RemoteDebugger/x64/msvsmon.exe and clicked on it to start it which states

> Msvsmon started a new server named 'Home'. Waiting for new connections.

I then searched for Firewall & network protection -> advanced settings -> inbound rules and made sure that there was a green check mark on Visual Studio 2022 Remote Debugger. I checked outbound rules and Visual Studio 2022 Remote Debugger is not on there, I saw that it was optional to add to outbound rules. So after doing all of that and closing out VS and re-opening it and trying to attach debugger again, I still come across the same error that I got before I did all of the requirements. I even turned off my firewall just to test it out and still got the same error message. Is there something that I am missing that is causing this error to still appear when I attempt to attach debugger?

Comment: Make sure Remote Debugging is enabled in Azure Portal. Azure Portal =>Your App Service =>Configuration => Select General settings. https://i.imgur.com/nVmTFUE.png

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that I also did that as well. I have it enabled and selected to 2022. @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT

Comment: Which framework and version you are using?

Comment: It is a net 6.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried to Debug the Application using VS 2022 with .Net 6.0.

> The Visual Studio 2022 Remote Debugger (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer. This may be because a firewall  is preventing communication to the remote computer. Please see Help for assistance on configuring remote debugging

- I got the same issue when i try to debug using ***Attach to Process*** option in Debug menu.
  [image]
- Place breakpoint in any of your form. As I am using the basic application ,I have placed in Index.cshtml.cs.
- Change the ***Configuration*** to ***Debug***  in Settings section and publish the Application to Azure.
- In the Hosting Section click on the Attach Debugger.
  [image]

[image]

Comment: Followed same with webjob. Not working for me.

Comment: @Techiemanu - Remote Debugging is Supported only for Continuous Web Jobs.Please refer [WebJob types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create#webjob-types).If you have any other issues to be resolved, please raise a new SO thread.

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT It is a continuous job only