# How can i remotely debug an asp.net core web app deployed on an azure app service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I am working on an asp.net core web application.

I need to debug this application (put a breakpoint and inspect variables when this breakpoint is hit).

I can do this on my local computer, with visual studio.

I can do it too if i deploy my web application on a remote IIS Server.

But i want to do this when my application is deployed on an azure app service.

This container does not work with IIS. It seems an azure app service works with Kestrel (dotnet run command). And i don't know how i can remotely debug this application.

Thanks

Additionnal informations:

- I am working with .Net6
- What i mean by "container" is "Azure app service instance"
- I am working with Visual Studio 2022 community edition
- I am deploying with azure devops and azure pipelines

Comment: What is the .net core version ? Version of Visual Studio you are using ?

Comment: And how you are deploying your web app to azure ?

Comment: What do you mean by "This container does not work with IIS"? Are you deploying a Docker container in App Service?

Comment: Refer [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70713964/visual-studio-2022-debug-azure-app-service/70737737#70737737)

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT I can't attach to the process because this is a remote process...

Comment: I think the answer here is, *with great difficulty*. The better solution would be to re-create whatever it is your trying to debug locally.

Comment: I can’t re-create anything because this is an app service not a virtual machine. I need to debug through dotnet run process

Comment: Have you tried [Attach Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xeE7.png)

Comment: It does not work for .Net6...

Answer (score 0):

If you want use remote debug feature, you need to use `Debug` model when you deploy your webapp.

Something like below in Visual Studio.

[image]

In azure devops, you can find it like:

1. `Pipelines` > `Builds (or Pipelines)`, open your build pipeline
2. Click in Edit, `Variables` tab, change the value from variable BuildConfiguration from "release" to "debug"

Comment: It does not work because this is an app service on azure. Your method would work for a server with IIS for example

Comment: @Bob5421 Ok，pls enable remote debug in your azure portal. It should be work，pls try it.

Comment: @Bob5421 Find configurations and scroll down, find enable remote debug options.

Comment: @Bob5421 Does it useful to you ?

Comment: Sorry but no :(