# ASP .NET Connect to Azure Process and debug

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2022, remote-debugging, azure-cloud-services

I am trying to debug a deployed service on Azure Cloud by attaching to the process "w3wp.exe".

1. Set Remote Debugging - On in Azure Cloud.
2. Debug -> Attach Process -> Connection type: Microsoft Azure App Services -> Login then select the Web App from Cloud -> Select process **w3wp**
3. Tools -> Options -> Debugging

- 'Enable Just My Code' **unchecked**
  Symbols load, takes 1-2 minutes then an error appears:

```
System.IO.IOException
  HResult=0x80131620
  Message=Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
  Source=System.Net.Sockets
  StackTrace:
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Inner Exception 1:
SocketException: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
```

- 'Enable Just My Code' **checked**
  Symbols are not loaded. I put a breakpoint on a simple Get method and VS warns me:
  `The breakpoint will not be hit. Symbols have not been loaded for the current document.`

Questions:

1. Do you know how can I debug my remote Azure Web app? What am I doing wrong?
2. My seniors told me it is no longer possible due to security concerns from Microsoft developers. The remote debugging is now disabled. I don't know if its true.
   Do you know any update on this? Can I still from local Visual Studio 2022 attach to an Azure Cloud Web App and debug on my computer the remote application?

Answer (score 0):

> To debug a deployed service on Azure Cloud by attaching to the process "w3wp.exe",

**Steps to debug**

- In Visual Studio, go to Debug -> Attach Process.

[image]

- In the Attach to Process dialog, select Connection type as `Microsoft Azure App Services`.
- And click on find and it will prompt to login with your Azure account and select the Web App from Cloud.

[image]

[image]

- Select the process w3wp.
- In Visual Studio, go to Tools -> Options -> Debugging and make sure 'Enable Just My Code' is unchecked.
- And wait for symbols to load.
- If you get an error then `Enable Just My Code`  and see if the symbols load.

[image]

Debugging code.

[image]

- Run the application with a debug point.
- Then the debugger hits the breakpoint and allows you to step through the code.

To follow another approach, refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70713964/visual-studio-2022-debug-azure-app-service/70737737#70737737) link.

Comment: The behaviour is still as described in the question. If checkbox is checked or unchecked. If checked  the breakpoint is not hit because symbols are not loaded. If unchecked, I get a socket IO exception.

Comment: Check this check this [approach-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70713964/visual-studio-2022-debug-azure-app-service/70737737#70737737) and [approach-2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76222026/azure-remote-debugging-in-vs-with-scaled-out-application/76226638#76226638)