# Azure Remote Debugging in VS With Scaled Out Application

Tags: c#, azure, remote-debugging

I doubt it is possible, but can I attach a remote debugger in Visual Studio with a scaled out app? I have 2 instances of my app services running in Azure. I'm able to attach the debugger with symbols but I never hit my breakpoints. Has anyone tried this? I've done some searching but haven't found anything helpful.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into this SO [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76172891/asp-net-connect-to-azure-process-and-debug/76179396#76179396)

Comment: Yes, it is possible to attach a remote debugger in Visual Studio with a scaled-out app. You need to attach the debugger to the correct instance of your app service.

Comment: @RajeshM no not yet. I have Azure set up and simply attached the debugger via the panel. I'll try attaching the process today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- After publishing the Web app to azure, you need to configure the `Remote debugging to` **On** and Visual Studio version as mentioned below.

[image]

- Download profile and use the application name.

[image]

`applicationName`.azurewebsites.net:4024

As below

[image]

Then you need to enter the credentials to connect the Azure, using the credentials from the downloaded profile.

[image]

- And choose the `worker process (W3wp.exe)` for debugging.
- Hit the URL of the published azure web App.
  then it attaches the debugger with symbols and then the debugger is hit in local Visual studio.

[image]